# how to change the red color in image to white

Tags: python, rgb

iam working on image plate recognition it require a preprocessing process to the image plate before the plate start to recognize , iam facing problems with red color plates the character is unclear to be segmented

is there away to transform the red color only to white for RGB image ?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this? If so post your code, otherwise attempt prior to asking. In any case see the following: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Comment: all I know is that I can change the value of pixels in the red channel for the RGB but I want  a formula to the color so there is no red color in the image

Comment: @Hassan_mohammad just set the red channel to zero for every pixel. Then the image won't have any red color.

Comment: @MaxxikCZ this will effect the other colors in the image cause the pixel color is a combination of those, iam thinking to detect the value of the red and compare it to other channel but I don't know the value and range

Comment: Oh sorry. What do you consider red? Exactly `(255, 0, 0)`? Then for each pixel you'd check whether each pixel is red and then change it to `(255, 255, 255)`. If you consider red something that is close to red then create a threshold value and sum the differences of each of the pixel's channels to red. If the value is under the threshold then set it to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cv2 will make your life a lot easier for this. There is an 'inRange' function which allows you to define your range of reds. This will be easier in the hsv color space, where red is a rectangle, than in the rgb space where red is a hard-to-capture chunk of a cube like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#/media/File:RGB_color_solid_cube.png).  In the below I get the hue for red :

```
img_arr = cv2.imread("/path/to/img.png")
red = np.uint8([[[0,0,255 ]]])
hsv_red = cv2.cvtColor(red,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Then define low and high end of the red range, by subtracting/adding 10 or 20 (arbitrary values you can change depending on what exactly you think of as red) . You've got to deal with red which is at the very ends of the hsv range as implemented in opencv so the following,which you could use for other colors,   will not be ok for red

```
red_low = np.array([hsv_red[0]-10,50,50])
red_high = np.array([hsv_red[0]+10,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, red_low, red_high)
```

Instead you would have to use something like

```
red_low = np.array(0,50,50])
red_high = np.array(20,255,255])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, red_low, red_high)
```

and do this whole business again for the reds at the high end of the hsv range. The cv2 hues go from 0 to 179 and not from 0 to the standard 255 .

```
red_low = np.array(160,50,50])
red_high = np.array(179,255,255])
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, red_low, red_high)
```

Now you make a final mask, which is the 'or' of the two red masks, and bitwise_and the mask (after inverting it since you want to lose only the reds instead of keeping only reds) with the image to get a result:

```
mask = mask1+mask2
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv_img,hsv_img, mask= mask_inv)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It seems to work ok , eg on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDcE4.jpg) image

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation